# Creating View/table with custom column

Tags: sql, clickhouse

I would like to create view with column with custom values

```
CREATE VIEW My_view AS
SELECT [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8] as numbers
```

I expect to have table with one column and 8 values (it's not necessary numbers)

Comment: One column, yes. Do you expect 8 rows, or one row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way:

```sql
CREATE VIEW My_view AS
SELECT arrayJoin([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]) AS numbers

/* or */

CREATE VIEW My_view AS
SELECT number
FROM numbers(1, 8)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 create view my_view as
   select 1 as column_1 union all
   select 2 as column_1 union all
   select 3 as column_1 union all
   etc....
```